# Is it possible to create independent chunks for reuse in different apps?

Tags: webpack

The main idea is to generate vendor.js once and reuse across whatever apps I need.

I stucked with HTMLWebpackPlugin and my own plugin on top of it creating a global-scoped module and changing src tags of script pointing to general vendor.js hosted on CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin). Several apps can reference the same `dll`. The `dll` files should be included manually in your html template or via [html-webpack-include-assets-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-include-assets-plugin)

> Usage DllReferencePlugin and DllPlugin are used in separate webpack
>   configs.

webpack.vendor.config.js

```
new webpack.DllPlugin({
  context: __dirname,
  name: '[name]_[hash]',
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'manifest.json'),
});
```

webpack.app.config.js

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  context: __dirname,
  manifest: require('./manifest.json'),
  name: './my-dll.js',
  scope: 'xyz',
  sourceType: 'commonjs2'
});
```

Comment: It's good only for production mode, but how can I achieve the same for dev? 
1 - exclude some modules from build
2 - somehow point to webpack-dev-server with dll